# Review Helpfulness Datasets

Tags: dataset

My team is looking for a user review dataset which we can compare to one of [these](http://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/) Amazon datasets.

The dataset needs to include text reviews and a review helpfulness rating. I know this is a long-shot, but if anyone knows of a dataset we could use then that would be great!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Okay, will do. Thanks, Erwan.